# Start_url not in ServiceWorker's scope for lighthouse PWA audit "localhost"

Tags: javascript, geolocation, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, lighthouse

***EDIT:*** If I change SW registration to: -

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('/Brotkrumen/echo.js')
```

I get the Install event but ServiceWorker is never READY.

If you run my [Brotkrumen](https://richardmaher.github.io/Brotkrumen/TravelManager.html) PWA from GitHub Pages you'll see from the console log that I get a PWA Install Event and everything is peachy (I'm writing the nice install pop up this w/e). The Lighthouse audit is all green.

The problem is when I run the same code from the local copy of the repository: -

http://localhost:3333/brotkrumen/travelmanager.html

I get this error: -

[image: LightHouse Audit]

This is my manifest: -

```
{
  "short_name": "Brotkrumen",
  "name": "Brotkrumen Web App",
  "description": "Native Background Geolocation POC",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "gingerbreadhouse.png",
      "sizes": "48x48 128x128 144x144 192x192 512x512",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "any"
    },
    {
      "src": "gingerbreadhouse.png",
      "sizes": "48x48 128x128 144x144 192x192 512x512",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "/Brotkrumen/TravelManager.html",
  "background_color": "#00ccdd",
  "theme_color": "#00ccdd",
  "display": "fullscreen"
}
```

The start_url above and my Service Worker registration scope as follows: -

```
navigator.serviceWorker.register('echo.js', { scope: './' })
```

These settings were the only combo to work on both the case-sensitive GitHub pages and IIS.

IIS Physical path "C:\repos" with a "Brotkrumen" sub-folder.

In both environments all code and Service Workers function as expected. Except for Windows\Chrome\lighthouse spotting the PWA.

Case sensitive Windows???

Comment: service worker will be installed only with Https protocol. I guess your local host is http.

Comment: @RajeshG please be aware of the exception to the httpS rule for "localhost"

Comment: What is your question? Service worker and manifest.json scopes are case sensitive and will have to match.

Comment: @abraham please see the relevant code included above and complete repository at https://github.com/RichardMaher/Brotkrumen Most importantly, please see the Lighthouse error above. Q: With the exact same codebase, why does lighthouse audit pass with GitHub pages/linux and fail with Windows IIS? This only started happening after I had to introduct the subfolder URLs for GitHub pages.

Comment: Service worker scopes are case sensitive `brotkrumen` is a different scope from `Brotkrumen`.

Comment: @abraham please see where I specify the sope as "./" where do you suggest the "brotkrumen" is coming from. By the way I have experimented with all combos of scope and path I can think of and still no joy/ If you think you have the answer please say "chany this to this and it will work". Once again it works on case-sensitive GitHub pages but not tolerant IIS.

Comment: `brotkrumen` is the scope the service worker is registered to.

Comment: @abraham I can read the error message too. How/where do I control/change it? {scope: '/Brotkrumen/'} does not work. And why does it currently work on case-sensitive linux i.e. GH pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad :-( or, at least, My Disbelief!

The only "problem" is the "b" in the browser navigation/URL bar. This works on Windows/IIS: -

```
http://localhost:3333/Brotkrumen/travelmanager.html
```

It's as simple as that. And, before you ask, yes it was one of the first things I tried but I didn't realize that Chrome Browser History would see a case-insensitive "exact" match and replace what I typed with the "old" lower-case version. (And, yes, I wasn't paying attention) Once I deleted the "old" url from history and entered the new one, all lighthouse audits were passed.

I enetered a [bug](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/13700) with Lighthouse but they disagreed.

For me Windows' *and Chrome's* case-insensitivity needs to be respected/honoured with a case-INCENSITIVE compare by Lighthouse. Linux/GitHub won't find the sub-folder in the first place, and all other URL case checks (caching etc) are enforced so there is no regression here?

Or Chrome become case sensitive?

Anyway, all's well that ends.